# Why Do IC Specs Only List Voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microprocessor, circuit-design

I'm a bit of a beginner at circuit design, and wanted to tinker around with creating a circuit that uses a [z80](http://www.zilog.com/appnotes_download.php?FromPage=DirectLink&dn=PS0178&ft=Product%20Specification%20(Data%20Sheet)%20%20&f=YUhSMGNEb3ZMM2QzZHk1NmFXeHZaeTVqYjIwdlpHOWpjeTk2T0RBdmNITXdNVGM0TG5Ca1pnPT0=) microprocessor. I found a pinout diagram, which shows that the chip I'm looking at uses 5V (a range of 4.5 to 5.5).

My question is, 5 V..at *what*. Clearly, current does matter as there are much more powerful and higher-clocked ICs running a 1.5 V; and it doesn't take a genius to figure out that connecting it to 12 A would cause it to instantly explode or catch on fire.

Would I be right in assuming that the correct approach would be to measure the resistance and calculate the current using Ohm's law? And if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You write "it doesn't take a genius to figure out that connecting it to 12 A would cause it to instantly explode or catch on fire". That is not at all the case. You don't seem to understand how electronics works. It is utterly irrelevant how much current a 5V power supply is capable of delivering, as long as it is enough. Connect that part to a 5V supply capable of 1000A, and the part will take the same current, and will not be harmed. No, it is not a good idea to measure its resistance. Please post a link to the datasheet. It will give ways to calculate its current requirements.

Comment: No. No. No. No. No. Just No. Start with resistors & LEDs. Don't make that poor Z80 suffer unnecessarily.

Comment: @gbulmer Um. I may be a beginner but I'm preeeettty sure that's not true. I was just reading through the data sheet and found the section where they explain how the current effects the clock speed. at 20mA, the clock speed is 6 MHz, at 100mA, it's 20MHz. if I plugged this thing up to 1000A, logically speaking, it would be overclocked to like 2.0GHz. I've seen much higher quality cpus catch on fire with much less overclocking.

Comment: Its the other way around. At 6MHz it draws 20mA, at 20MHz, it draws 100mA.

Comment: @WesleyLee oh, I see. So basically, ICs only take the current that they need and no more. Setting the clock speed is something done at a software level, which would change how much current the component draws.

Comment: Post a link to the device datasheet please. I don't want to make you feel bad, but you really do not understand how an active device like a processor works. Your logic is exactly wrong. The clock speed is set by a crystal, and some internal electronics. The datasheet is explaining that if you want it to run at 20MHz, it needs a supply capable of at least 100mA, but if you only want to run it at 6MHz, then it only needs 6mA. The datasheet tells you *exactly* how much current it needs.

Comment: http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/z8400.pdf

Comment: Well, I've read that ICs use a multiplier. When I said, "at a software level", I was meaning controlling a programmable clock generator

Comment: That isn't a datasheet. It's 4 pages long. A datasheet is likely to be hundreds of pages.

Comment: oops, wrong one: http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/ps0178.pdf

Comment: @DeftlyHacked - Just FYI the documents at http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/z8400.pdf and http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/ps0178.pdf which you linked, are not those for the original Z80, but for a much later version. Later versions have reduced the current which they require, and hence this changes some of the specific current requirements being mentioned in the answers and comments. However that doesn't change the point that none of the versions would use all 12A (or 1000A) from the PSU in your examples.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. So long story short, ICs _draw_ current, they don't get _fed_ current; how much current the ICs draw depends on their clock speed, which depends on the speed of both the IC and the clock generator.

Comment: @brhans I chose z80's precisely for the reason that I expect to make a few of them suffer before I figure exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @DeftlyHacked - yes, a load (that IC) draws (uses) current. It can't be overfeed at its rated voltage. It isn't a simple resistor. It's resistance varies from micro-second to micro-second as subsets of the thousands of transistors inside it switch on and off. It uses more current when its transistors switch faster, not the other way around. You can't make the transistors switch faster with more current, but with a faster clock.

Comment: Ohms law!!! The IC has an internal resistance. With the right voltage level, and a specified internal resistance, the right amount of current will flow through the chip. A higher voltage with the same resistance in the IC means more current will flow through the chip. A lower voltage with the same resistance in the IC, means less current flows through the IC.

Comment: Thank you @Bradman175, that actually made things much much clearer to me!

Comment: So in summation of how a cpu works: a voltage is applied to a crystal, and through properties of piezoelectricity it generates a magnetic field that generates another voltage with a resonant frequency. This voltage is applied to the clock pin of the circuit, where it's multiplied and converted into a square wave. The difference in pitch causes a tick, that recursively turns the gates of the transistors on and off. This causes a change in the resistivity of the circuit. And thus, as a side effect, the current that the circuit draws fluctuates proportionately.

Answer (score 5):

The [Z80 datasheet](http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/ps0178.pdf) you have linked to in your comments clearly shows on page 34

Icc1 Power Supply Current
4MHz   20mA
6MHz   30mA
8MHz   40mA
10MHz  50mA
20MHz  100mA

They are all rated for a Vcc = 5V

So, the way to read that is, this device will use this much current, at 5V, when the clock runs at these speeds.

It uses more current as the clock speed (which is driving it, with a crystal, or external clock source) is increased.

It is not symmetric. It does not run faster if more current is supplied.

If the supply isn't capable of supplying enough current the IC will likely stop working correctly, and will not gracefully slow down.

So, among many other parameters, the datasheet specifies exactly how much current the IC uses, and under what conditions.

An IC is not a simple resistance. That device is thousands of transistors. It's actual current consumption will vary at a similar rate to the clock speed, i.e. its current consumption will vary within a microsecond. So trying to measure its current consumption is almost futile if you want to design a circuit using it. That is why the datasheet does specify its *maximum* current consumption, and operating conditions. It would be practically impossible to design a robust and reliable circuit using the part without that data.

Summary: Your 12A power supply will do it no harm. However, it isn't sufficient to have something capable of delivering that much power. The IC will also need a capacitor physically close to it, to handle that sub-microsecond current variation.

Answer (score 3):

> Why Do IC Specs Only List Voltage?

They don't only list the (required) voltage. IC datasheets list many other parameters including the maximum current requirement.

> it doesn't take a genius to figure out that connecting it to 12 A would cause it to instantly explode or catch on fire.

That's not true; an IC draws the current which it requires, not all available current.  There are various similar questions on EE.SE about how to choose a power supply, which explain this point.

FYI, a quick check of some datasheets show that the CMOS version of the original Z80 requires around 50mA at 10MHz; the NMOS version of the original Z80 requires up to 200mA.  You could connect either of those to a 5V power supply capable of providing 12A (to use your example), and in simplified terms:

- they would work fine;
- they would use *only* the current which they required and would **not** use all the available 12A.

Answer (score 2):

IC's list both no load static current and dynamic current as various voltages and speeds.  Since current is non-linear a resistance measurement is of no value using a DMM.